# ansible conditionally set a value if complex object exists

Tags: ansible

In my ansible role, I conditinally include a task that runs a [`cloudformation`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cloudformation_module.html) module, then register the stack outputs

```
- name: a cloudformation template
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: mystack
    state: present
    template: someTemplate.yml
    template_parameters:
      SomeParameter: someValue
  register: my_stack
```

Since this task may or may not get run, `my_stack` will either be empty or it will look like:

```
my_stack:
  stack_outputs:
    var1: something
    var2: something_else
    var3: etc
```

I'd like to include one of these variables in `my_stack.stack_outputs` in another task *if* it is defined, otherwise use an empty string (`''`)

I've tried in another [`cloudformation`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cloudformation_module.html) to conditionally add in `my_stack.stack_outputs.var1` if defined, otherwise a `''` but am getting errors

The task is:

```
- name: another cloudformation template
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: my_new_stack
    state: present
    template: someOtherTemplate.yml
    template_parameters:
      SomeOtherParameter: "{{ (my_stack.stack_outputs.var1 is defined) | ternary(my_stack.stack_outputs.var1, '') }}"
```

This works if the original task (`mystack`) was run, but if not, I get an error on the `ternary` part of the second task

```
"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stack_outputs'
```

How can I set the `SomeOtherParameter` to an empty string if the original `mystack` never ran, but set it correctly if `mystack` *did* run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Better solution: Use the Jinja2 `default` filter:

```
((my_stack | default({})).stack_outputs | default({})).var1 | default('')
```

First we check if `my_stack` exists; if it doesn't we use `{}`.  Then we check if that thing's `stack_outputs` exists; in the case that we're looking at `{}.stack_outputs` it will be an obvious no, while in the case that it was `my_stack` it will.  Repeat again for `var1`.

---

You need to test it further back.  If you can trust that `my_stack` is only going to be unset or have the full value, you can just do

```
(my_stack is defined)
```

Otherwise, you'll need to do something like

```
(my_stack is defined and my_stack.stack_outputs is defined and my_stack.stack_outputs.var1 is defined)
```

Operator short-circuiting will mean that if `my_stack` does not exist, it won't try to access `my_stack.stack_output`.  Similarly, if that doesn't exist it won't continue on to try to access `my_stack.stack_outputs.var1`

Comment: Even with adding the mutiple `is defined ` statements, the first argument on the `ternary` filter is what is throwing the error because `my_stack` doesn't have a `stack_outputs` object

Comment: This is true; it turns out it's more annoying than I expected.  It looks like you have to use `default` to test each layer, replacing it with a null object.  I *think* my new example should work.

Comment: Very creative.  the `default` filter works perfectly! Thanks!